# Create a custom serializable value type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to create a custom object `struct/class` that is serialized to string instead of object.
So
for eg.

```
[Serializable]
struct MySerializableStringType : ISerializable
{
   public string _myProp

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("myprop", _myProp,  typeof(string));
        }

        public MySerializableStringType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            _myProp= (string) info.GetValue("myprop", typeof(string));
        }

}
```

This above implementation gives me `{ "myprop" : "myvalue" }`. I want to tweak the above code so that on serializing it just gives a string `"myvalue"`. Can it be done?

Essentially if I had another object

```
class AnotherClass
{
 MySerializableStringType  myString;
 string systemString;
}
```

this class should serialize as
`{ 'myString': 'value', 'systemString':'value'}`

N.B. **I am not looking for a custom JsonSerializer based solution**. I want it to be purely handled at the c# object level.

Comment: But `Serializable` doesn't serialize to JSON in the first place. If you have custom code that can take a `Serializable` object and turn it into JSON, that's the bit to investigate. `Serializable` dictates no on-the-wire format, but is primarily intended to be used with binary serialization, and there the type (class) is an integral part of things -- if you serialized to a `string`, it would also be deserialized as one. A possible alternate approach is to give your class custom conversion operators to/from `string` and use a DTO for the serialization.

Comment: I get the bit about deserialize back from string. There is other piece of code that I did not share above, as it may not be part of the final solution. But I have an Explicit cast operators that I'm hoping will handle the deserialization. And its ok even if it doesnt. More interested in the serialization though

Comment: @Gusman lol. ok then.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing also means that deserializing later. But what you want is one way trip. If you remove field names how could you deserialize safely? As a solution to serialize only I would suggest overriding ToString method.

Comment: System.DateTime serializes to string. And goes back to DateTime too. No?

Comment: @CodeReaper: that depends on the serialization used, actually. For binary serialization (the "normal" use case for `Serializable`) the answer is [a definite "no"](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,784). You can certainly serialize/deserialize a type to `string` in any way you please, but only as long as the serialization mechanism offers an option for it.

Comment: @CodeReaper: Parsing a string to date or another type requires format knowledge. i.e. 12.1.xxxx could be 12th of Jan or 1st of Dec depending on culture you use. That is why it is called parse not deserialization in many programming languages. A good serialization should be self explaining.

Comment: @haltunbay which is exactly why we have standards, like ISO 8601

Comment: @JeroenMostert As an example, System.DateTime is serialized by Newtonsoft, where was the custom rule added? Did Microsoft add a custom serializer for Newtonsoft, that, "hey Newtonsoft, use this for our DateTime". AFAIK, I didn't see that attribute on DateTime. *OR*, did newtonsoft handle this on their end, that "whenever we get DataTime, as an exception we will serilialize it as a string". Again, how can it even tell that its datetime?

Comment: @CodeReaper: Microsoft has nothing to do with how Newtonsoft.JSON serializes. In fact, I'm pretty sure (but not absolutely sure) Newtonsoft.JSON completely ignores `Serializable`/`ISerializable` and whatever you add to implement it; it's certainly no requirement to make JSON serialization work. It cannot tell from the JSON itself that something is a date/time since JSON has no type for that, so it uses either the type of the property you use to deserialize into, or guesswork if you're deserializing into a dynamic type.